# Rumbling sound from brakes in Lexus

Tags: brakes, noise, lexus

My family has a 2013 Lexus RX 350. Today was the first time we noticed a low rumbling sound coming from the brakes when they are pushed. We've had a maintenance check with no issues a month ago. Any thoughts what might be causing this sound, and if there is anything we should do?

Comment: What did the technician actually say when you had the brakes inspected? Was there any indication given as to the amount of friction material left on the brake pad?

Comment: No issue with the brakes was noted. To your second question - I don't think so.

Comment: Do you see the ABS warning light on?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience this is worn brake pads, have them replaced. Sometimes they wear unevenly because of poor alignment, or a bad bushing, or a rock stuck in the caliper. Replace the pads. Inspect the old pads for abnormal wear patterns. Report back. If you aren't sure, take it to a mechanic.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things this could be. The simplest (and cheapest!) is the brake pad wear sensor - telling you the pads are getting low and need to be replaced. You should be able to tell this by looking at the pads (you may need to take the wheels off to do so)

Can you tell if it comes from one particular wheel, or more than one? Is it more of a rumbling or a grinding type sound? Does it only do it in a straight line, or when cornering, or both? Does it change in volume or pitch as you press the brake pedal harder?

Comment: It's noticeable when in slow traffic and I brake lightly. I've mainly noticed it when driving straight. More of a consistent, low rumbling (at first I thought it was someone's stomach grumbling) than a grinding sound. Not sure about the wheels. I just hear it when pressing the brakes.

Comment: So far every time I've seen that its due to broken brake pads. Once they get thin they tend to snap in half and the grinding is due to the free movement of the broken pads against the rotor instead of being held in place. There's usually a pin on each end of the pad holding it in place.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm yaa its wright it increases the volume when we press the break pidle harder and if disk are new some times the disk pads where soo hard metal.it sounds like keeskees.